# Psuedo element to display behind parent divs text but in front of parent div

Tags: css

I have a psuedo element which is a pink background inside a div like so:

```
<div>
  Hello
</div>

div {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Also here is a codepen to show what I mean: http://codepen.io/acha5066/pen/oXVPzg I want the pink background in front of the green background but behind the text Hello. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0 /* we etablish a new stacking context */
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
</div>
```

A good article that will help you to understand the stacking context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context